# Why am I not getting coverage for my attacmentclass

Tags: apex, unit-test, attachment, blob.topdf

I have a extension class to attach a PDF to a record. I made Unittest which status gives succes but my code still has no coverage, why is this?

Class:

```
public with sharing class attachPDF {

private final Quote obj;

    public attachPDF(ApexPages.StandardController standardPageController) {
        obj = (Quote)standardPageController.getRecord(); 
    }
    public PageReference attachPDF() {

        PageReference pdfPage = Page.OfferteAmac;
        pdfPage.getParameters().put('id',obj.id);

        Blob pdfBlob = pdfPage.getContent(); 

        Attachment attach = new Attachment(parentId = obj.Id, Name = 'Offerte ' + date.today().format() +'.pdf', body = pdfBlob); 
        insert attach;

        PageReference pageWhereWeWantToGo = new ApexPages.StandardController(obj).view(); 

        pageWhereWeWantToGo.setRedirect(true); 
        return pageWhereWeWantToGo;
    }

}
```

Test:

```
    @isTest
private class AttachPDFTest
{
    @isTest static void test_one()
    {

        Account acct = new Account(Name = 'testname');
        insert acct;

        Opportunity Opp = new Opportunity(Name = 'testname', StageName = 'Won' ,
                                          CloseDate = Date.newInstance(2030, 3, 16), AccountId = acct.Id );
        insert Opp; 

        Quote testobj = new Quote( name= 'TestQuote', OpportunityId = Opp.Id );
        insert testobj; 

        Test.startTest();
        Blob b = Blob.valueOf('Test Data');
        Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
        attachment.ParentId = testobj.ID;
        attachment.Name = 'Test Attachment for Parent';
        attachment.Body = b;
        insert(attachment);
        Test.stopTest();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you din't create class instance and called the class method.

As this is a extension class and not a trigger handler class so you need to manually call them from your test class

```
insert(attachment);
ApexPages.StandardController standardPageController = new ApexPages.StandardController(testobj);
attachPDF att =  new attachPDF (standardPageController);
att.attachPDF(); // it will be better if you keep your classname and method name different.

System.assert(); // based on your use case use the assert statement to verify code execution
```

Comment: I tried you solution but this doesnt work as I get: Methods defined as TestMethod do not support getContent call

Comment: @Thomas you need [mock callout](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_integration_services/units/apex_integration_rest_callouts)  as `getContent(); ` is treated as callout in salesforce.

Comment: I found a workaround but cant seen to get this working: 
        Blob content;
        if(Test.IsRunningTest())
        {
            content=Blob.ValueOf('UNIT.TEST');
        }
        else
        {
            content = attachment.getContent();
        }

Comment: @Thomas what is not working. Share your updated code.